# Python GUI programing using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a form which is having multiple rows.
By pressing enter it opens up a option window. But every time i hit enter it opens a new option window. How can i control and check if an option window is open then don't open an option window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

# Directory/File processing libraries
import os
import configparser
import csv

def callback():
    #messagebox.showinfo("Netezza", Folder_Name_var.get())
    #messagebox.showinfo("Netezza", Table_Name_var.get() )
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('C:\\aa\\config.ini')
    #for value in config['Folder']: print(value)
    for key in config.items('Folder'):
        print (key[1].replace('{Folder_Name}',Folder_Name_var.get()))
        os.makedirs(key[1].replace('{Folder_Name}',Folder_Name_var.get()),exist_ok=True)

def click_tv(event):
    #messagebox.showinfo("Inside")
    selected=trv.focus()
    print(trv.item(selected))

def press_enter(event):
    #messagebox.showinfo("Inside")
    selected=trv.focus()
    print(trv.item(selected))
    print(str((event.keysym)))
    if str((event.keysym))=='Return':
        option_wnd=Toplevel(root)
        option_wnd.geometry('200x200')
        option_wnd.title('Option Window')
        option_wnd.grab_set()
        #option_wnd.pack()
def selection_change(event):
    selected = trv.selection()[0]
    print('You clicked on', trv.item(selected))
    #option_wnd.mainloop()
root = Tk()

Folder_Name_var = tk.StringVar()
Table_Name_var = tk.StringVar()

# This is the section of code which creates the main window
root.geometry('873x498')
root.configure(background='#63B8FF')
root.title('Automation Software - Blue Shield of California')

pic= Canvas(root, height=100, width=100)
#pic= Canvas(root, height=225, width=580)

#picture_file = PhotoImage(file = 'c:\\aa\\bsc.png')
#pic.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=picture_file)
#pic.place(x=5, y=5)


lbl_Folder_Name = Label(root, text="Folder Name",background='#63B8FF').place(x=600, y=50)
lbl_Table_Name = Label(root, text="Table Name",background='#63B8FF').place(x=600, y=90)

txt_Folder_Name = Entry(root,textvariable = Folder_Name_var).place(x=700, y=50)
txt_Table_Name = Entry(root,textvariable = Table_Name_var).place(x=700, y=90)

Button(root, text="Show", width=10, command=callback).place(x=700,y=120)

tree_frame=Frame(root)
tree_frame.place(x=10,y=260)

tree_scroll=Scrollbar(tree_frame)
tree_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

style=ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("default")
style.map("Treeview",background=[('selected','bisque2')],foreground=[('selected','black')])

trv= ttk.Treeview(tree_frame,yscrollcommand=tree_scroll.set, columns=(1,2,3), show="headings", height="10")
trv.heading(1,text="Parameter", anchor=W)
trv.heading(2,text=" Parameter  Description", anchor=W)
trv.heading(3,text=" Specify your value", anchor=W)
trv.tag_configure('even',background="white")
trv.tag_configure('odd',background="steelblue")
trv.bind("<Double-1>",click_tv)
trv.bind("<Return>",press_enter)
trv.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>",selection_change)
trv.pack()
tree_scroll.config(command=trv.yview)


i=1

with open("c:\\aa\control.txt") as options:
    options_line = csv.reader(options, delimiter='\t')
    for option in options_line:
        #a=1
        if i%2==0:
            trv.insert(parent='', index='end', values=(option), tags=('even',))
            #print("even")
        else:
            trv.insert(parent='', index='end', values=(option), tags=('odd',))
            #print("odd")
        i=i+1
#trv.place(x=100,y=260)


root.mainloop()
```

Everytime I hit enter on the root window it opens a pop up window. I need to control the it. if the pop up window is open then we should not allow another pop up to open.
[image]

Comment: You have called `option_wnd.grab_set()` inside `press_enter()`, so you cannot trigger another `Enter` key press event on the treeview.  So I wonder how can you open another `option_wnd` without closing the existing one?

Answer (score 2):

The direct way is to use `winfo_exists()`:

```
root.option_wnd = None # Init value

def press_enter(event):
    #messagebox.showinfo("Inside")
    selected=trv.focus()
    print(trv.item(selected))
    print(str((event.keysym)))
    if str((event.keysym))=='Return': 
        if root.option_wnd and root.option_wnd.winfo_exists():
            root.option_wnd.lift() # make this window on the top.
        else: # create this window
            root.option_wnd  = tk.Toplevel(root)
            .....
```

---

But I don't think you need to create this window each time when user type <kbd>Enter</kbd>.Create it at the beginning, just show it when user type <kbd>Enter</kbd>

For example:

```
root = tk.Tk()
option_wnd = tk.Toplevel()
option_wnd.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", option_wnd.withdraw) # when user try to close this window, hide it instead of destroy it
.....


option_wnd.withdraw() # hide this window

def press_enter(event):
    #messagebox.showinfo("Inside")
    selected=trv.focus()
    print(trv.item(selected))
    print(str((event.keysym)))
    if str((event.keysym))=='Return': 
        option_wnd.deiconify() # show it.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not uses classes you could do the following:

```
options_displayed = False #global

def option_closed(w):
    global options_displayed
    w.destroy() #close the actual window
    options_displayed = False # log the fact it is now close

def press_enter(event):
    global options_displayed # reference global variable
    #messagebox.showinfo("Inside")
    selected=trv.focus()
    print(trv.item(selected))
    print(str((event.keysym)))
    if str((event.keysym))=='Return' and not options_displayed:
        option_wnd=Toplevel(root)
        option_wnd.geometry('200x200')
        option_wnd.title('Option Window')
        option_wnd.grab_set()
        option_wnd.grab_set()
        option_wnd.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda w= option_wnd :option_closed(w))
```

Comment: Wont you have to set `option_wnd` to not `None` inside the `if` ?

Comment: `option_wnd` is actually set to `Toplevel(root)`

Comment: I tried the above one. the if condition is executing but the option window is getting generated with root property.

Comment: After close this toplevel window, the `option_hwd` is not None. So user could open this window only once.

Comment: After changes the option window is not opening but still there is a window with root property is opening.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I thought the objective is to open it only once. If not the `option_wnd`must notify the main code that it is closed.

Comment: yes it should open once only. if the window is open it should not open another

Comment: @Basudev I update my answer to track the fact the `option_wnd` might be closed and hence need to be reopen

Comment: `option_win` cannot be closed because `option_win.destroy()` is not called inside `option_closed()` (the callback of `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`).  Actually you can use `option_wnd` instead of `options_displayed`.

Answer (score 0):

one option I can think of is binding the option window like this:

```
option_wnd.bind('<Return>', lambda e: option_wnd.close()) # or withdraw() or quit() ?
```

binding the option window to when enter is pressed it gets closed (althought I dont know about differences of above functions(there are so you should look up that)) but this can get in the way if you want to enter values using `Enter`(Return) key because it will close the window. The other option is to bind option window to this event:

```
option_wnd.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda e: option_wnd.close())
```

which is when window is not focused on anymore so if you pressed enter it would open a new one still bet the old one should be closed. Also you can try doing some logic programming with sth like when enter is presses 'turn on' a mode when pressing it again wont open window and when you close the existing window it will again allow that.

Comment: def press_enter(event):  
    global option_wnd 
    selected=trv.focus()
    print(trv.item(selected))
    print(str((event.keysym)))
    option_wnd=Toplevel(root)
    if str((event.keysym))=='Return' and option_wnd is None:
        option_wnd.geometry('500x500')
        option_wnd.title('Option Window')
        option_wnd.grab_set()
        print('state - ',option_wnd.state())
    else:
        option_wnd.title('in else')
        option_wnd.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda e: option_wnd.close())

Comment: its going to else but still opens new windows on hitting enter

Comment: are you telling this to me?

Answer (score 0):

```
def press_enter(event):
    #messagebox.showinfo("Inside")
    root.deiconify ()
    selected=trv.focus()
    print(trv.item(selected))
    print(str((event.keysym)))
    if str((event.keysym))=='Return':
        option_wnd=Toplevel(root)
        option_wnd.geometry('200x200')
        option_wnd.title('Option Window')
        option_wnd.grab_set()
        #option_wnd.pack()
```